# How do I change what's being displayed in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, menu

I don't really know how to word this question, but I can explain what I'm trying to do. 
I have my program drawing a basic menu with a background image and 3 buttons along the bottom. I want to make it so that when I press one of the buttons, the menu and the background image change to a different scene. Like pressing play to start a game or pressing options to go to an option menu.

This is my code for the primary menu:

```
private final void initUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(panel);

    panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setAlignmentX(1f);
    bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JButton plyBtn = new JButton("Play");
    plyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            GameFrame_Test1 game1 = new GameFrame_Test1();
            game1.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    JButton opBtn = new JButton("Options");


    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    bottom.add(plyBtn);
    bottom.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
    bottom.add(opBtn);
    bottom.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
    bottom.add(quitButton);
    bottom.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));

    panel.add(new GraphicTest_1());
    panel.add(bottom);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,15)));


    setTitle("Justice GUI");
    setSize(1280, 720);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DisplayFrame ex = new DisplayFrame();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my code for the frame I want to change to so far:

```
class GameFrame_Test1 extends JPanel{
    private Image mshi;

    public GameFrame_Test1() {

        loadImage();
        setSurfaceSize();
    }

    private void loadImage() {

        mshi = new ImageIcon("content/Placeholder_Map.png").getImage();
    }

    private void setSurfaceSize() {

        Dimension d = new Dimension();
        d.width = mshi.getWidth(null);
        d.height = mshi.getHeight(null);
        setPreferredSize(d);        
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(mshi, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}
```

I am very new to Java Swing, and this is a test program for me to learn how to use it. I have looked online for a solution, but not being able to word my question makes it hard. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make it so that when I press one of the buttons, the menu and the background image change to a different scene.

You should be using a `Card Layout` as the layout manager of the content panel. Then you can swap a different panel on the frame when a button is clicked.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: The tutorial I was using never mentioned Card Layout... I will look into it. Thanks!